# Gradle: Preventing Cyclic Dependencies in the Java Package Structure

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs

I have a Gradle build for a Java program and I would like to include static analysis to cause the build to fail if a cyclic dependency is found in the package structure.  Can FindBugs, for example, be configured to do this?  I currently have FindBugs defined in the `build.gradle` and it will stop the build for various problems but not for package cycles:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

findbugs {
    toolVersion = '3.0.1'
    effort = 'max'
    reportLevel = 'medium'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) for this. It has a standard Gradle plugin:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jdepend_plugin.html

You can configure the JDepend plugin to fail the build if there are warnings (in fact, I think that is the default).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas.  I tried adding an obvious cyclic dependency in the package structure and then added the following to the Gradle config:
`apply plugin: 'jdepend'`.  Unfortunately although JDepend clearly ran, it didn't stop the build for the package cycle.  I also tried with `jdepend {ignoreFailures = false}`but still no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: This should really work - did you check the source set configuration?

Comment: The source set configuration is fine.  JDepend generates output for the `main` source set during the build.  Furthermore, running `./gradlew :core:tasks --all` shows that `jdependMain` is one of the verification tasks included as part of `check`.

Comment: I see. Then I would suggest posting that as a new question. For Gradle, I sometimes get better results on the [Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/).

Comment: Anyone still looking for this, gradle's jdepend can be made to fail a build, follow http://sprinkl.be/2012/05/09/making-a-gradle-build-fail-when-jdepend-has-cycles/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try jadecy:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadecy/

When it computes packages cycles it also computes the classes that cause each package dependency, which is useful to figure out what's going on.
It also allows to compute classes cycles, if you ever need it.

It's more similar to jdeps than to JDepend, but was primarily designed
as a library (for usage in dependencies related unit tests), even though
it can also be used from command line.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, that's interesting.  Specifically, I need something to work in the Gradle build.  Is there a Gradle plugin for the project?